# How to manage files uploaded by users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, file, nginx

I have a web app which uses nginx. Suppose it's in Rails, but it doesn't really matter.

I'm planning to have around a hundred of pictures/files uploaded every day by users. I don't want to use any custom solution for storying and uploading images and instead I want to manage that myself.

1) Is there an idiomatic place/path where I should store those images? Or will any path within the reach of nginx will work?

2) Should it be a separate folder from the one that I'm use for storying images for CSS?

3) How would I organize folders forest? That is, should it be something like `/my_base_image_folder/{year}/{month}/{day}/{image_sequence_number}.jpg`?

Or maybe `/my_base_image_folder/{article_id}/{image_sequence_number}.jpg`? Or should I put them in the same folder `/my_base_image_folder/{img_guid}.jpg?

And why?

4) What's a recommended solution for naming uploading files? GUID? Or a sequence number?

Comment: I'm going to answer this based on the subject line since I'm not really sure what you mean about not using custom solutions but I would recommend handling files with paperclip and amazon S3 if using Ruby On Rails.  Files can be stored and associated to users easily and it's extremely flexible.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your use case for consuming those images again. If you're planning to retrieve images uploaded by the users for those users on later sessions, ie., if your users have to browse through their images in your application, it's better to store it in `a_public_folder/user_id_hashed/`. If you're planning to retrieve images based on the uploaded time or date, it's better if you go with `a_public_folder/year/month/day/..`. Make sure the public folder is accessible by your ngnix by using not-too-open permission, just to be safe. Also, naming the image files, a combination of timestamp and a small random hex should do I guess, no big deal.